# Internet Explorer img width when "alt" text is displayed

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have created the following jsfiddle as an example to show the issue I am seeing in IE. In IE, if the `<img>` tag has an invalid src, then the width is calculated (somehow) based on the `alt` attribute. In other browsers this does not seem to be the case.

http://jsfiddle.net/DLrHL/2/

Check that from multiple browsers, Chrome, FF, IE, Safari - Chrome, FF & Safari all behave the same - the `img` with the `alt` tag is not sized differently that then one without. But IE changes the width of the `img` considerably depending on the length of the `alt`.

Is there some way I can make IE behave like other browsers? (at least in this regard)

**Edit:**

What I want is that if the image is available, it should use the height i specify in css & set width automatically. If the image is not available, I don't care about the height but the width should be exactly what is required for the alt text.

Comment: Behavior is reversed to me

Comment: interesting. in either case, is there an option in html or css to make the `img` tag not expand based on the `alt` attribute?

Comment: Can you tell us why you don't want to specify the `src` attribute of an image??

Comment: @ashutosh `img {width}` and for img with alt you can try `img[alt] {width}`

Comment: @enyce12 - its not that i don't want to specify the src. sometimes the site i am developing has invalid urls in src. i don't want that case to show up as huge widths depending upon the `alt` attr. it would be fine if the `img` had the exact size o the `alt` attr, but even that isn't the behavior i see.

Comment: @Mr.Alien - your suggestion might (i haven't tried it yet) help applying different rules for when alt is present and not present. but i'm not sure what width i can specify that would make it work for valid and invalid `src` urls that both have `alt` tags. `width:auto` is the obvious choice, but that is where the issue is seen.

Comment: In Firefox 27, both the width and the height of the second `img` element in the jsfiddle are determined by the amount of `alt` text (probably because it is displayed as simple inline element). But the question is really: *What do you want?* How should an `img` element be displayed when the image cannot be shown? If you want specific dimensions, just set them (and consider whether content overflow is possible and how it should be handled), and set `img { display: inline-block }`.

Comment: In FF, the image does not adhere to the `height:128px` you have set via CSS – _that_ behavior is what I would call definitively wrong!

Comment: So I am seeing different behaviour between FF on Windows & FF on Mac as well. Bottom line is - what I want is that if the image is available, it should use the height i specify in css & set width automatically. If the image is not available, I don't care about the height but the width should be exactly what is required for the alt text. Updating the question to make this requirement clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the image beforehand, then you can specify the width of the image, that fixed the problem for me, with IE.

I changed the width like this:

```
img {
    width: 128px; /* the width has been specified */
    height: 128px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DLrHL/3/

Comment: agreed, but in my case i do not know the width in advance.